# Forecast is simply equal to the lag of the original time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, lags, exponential-smoothing

I am currently dealing with the problem of **short time series** which often involves naive models as they already perform well enough. So I implemented an **exponential smoothing** that follows

$$
F_t = \alpha y_{t-1} + (1-\alpha)f_{t-1}
$$

where $F_t$ is the forecast value now based  on the smoothed value of the true value of the previous time step $y_{t-1}$ and the previous forecast $f_{t-1}$ which was simply taken as the average of all previous true values (a.k.a. the expanding mean in Python).

I'm investigating the **impact of the choice of alpha** and generally, at least for my specific use case, $\alpha \geq 0.9$ performs well. **But if you scrutinize the forecasted time series, it is simply a lagged version of the original time series**. I did a visual inspection on this, and also calculated the **correlation** between the forecast for each alpha and a lag 1 of $y$.

**My main question is, is a forecast which is simply a lag of the original time series said to be a good fit since the r2-score says so?** I understand, this may be an overfit, but if you compare other values of alpha, they're already negative r2.

Here's a graph to visualize:
[image]

Comment: R2 is never a good indicator for anything useful by itself IMO.  I would judge based on a holdout accuracy or you can use the state space representation of ETS and get an information criterion.  Just by looking at your data there is a trend so theoretically it makes sense that the best it could do is predict the last value.

Comment: @Tylerr i've only stated looking into TS so I'll need to read up on state space representations. Thanks for this!